# How do I remove the .NET Compact Framework from my Windows Mobile 5 device?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0

I'm trying to get a number of third party applications to work on my Windows Mobile 5 smartphone.

I've installed the latest version (3.5) of the Microsoft.NET Compact Framework, but whenever I run the apps I get an error message which states: "This application [Application Name] requires a newer version of the Microsoft .NET Compact Framework than the version installed on this device."

Given I've supposedly successfully installed the latest version, this doesn't make sense, leading me to believe I need to remove the .NET Compact Framework and start again. (I've tried reinstalling it, but as far as I can tell there's no automated way of removing it on the device, or from my PC.)

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's probably better to *not* uninstall, and if it's on the device in ROM you can't uninstall it anyway.

There are a couple options available to you.

1. The different CF versions coexist fine, so you can install the older version and leave 3.5 on it.
2. The CF can be set for compatibility mode.  That means you can tell just a single app compiled against an old version use the 3.5 runtimes in compatibility mode or you can set that device-wide so *all* older CF apps will run agains the 3.5 EE in compatibility mode.

For online resources discussing configuration files and compatibility mode, see these links:

- [MSDN Article on Configuration File Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629366.aspx)
- [MSDN Article on Configuring Runtime Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5cd9b2c.aspx)
- [David Kline's blog on Compatibility Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidklinems/archive/2005/04/19/409541.aspx)
- [The CF 3.5 Power Toys](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C8174C14-A27D-4148-BF01-86C2E0953EAB&displaylang=en) (includes an app for setting configurations)

Note: I forgot to mention in the original response that using option #2 (running against CF 3.5) will very likely improve the performance of the app as well, since it will be running with the newest CLR.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Microsoft ActiveSync to uninstall it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed it yourself you should be able to remove it by going to Settings -> System -> Remove Programs (could be a slightly different path on the smartphone OS, I'm used to Pocket PCs).