# .NET CF 3.5 and .NET CF 2.0 on the same mobile device

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I have developed .net cf application for a windows mobile 6.5.3 device (the Motorola ES400).

I am using sql ce to persist data in the application and have installed the required sql ce runtime libraries for it. Since my application specifically uses some custom UI controls I purchased for .net cf 2.0, I have installed the .net cf 2.0.

Question - Can .net cf 3.5 and .net cf 2.0 coexist on the same mobile device? Can I expect any problems with respect to the api calls in .net?

Please advice.

Subbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With work you can get them to co-exist, but there's no good reason to do it.  CF 3.5 can run CF 2.0 applications and CF 3.5 apps can load CF 2.0 assemblies.  In the rare event it won't "just run" you can even fall back to compatibility mode. See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96750/how-do-i-remove-the-net-compact-framework-from-my-windows-mobile-5-device) for some more info and links.